# It is possible to use BoxedApp SDK with powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

It is possible to load BoxedApp SDK dll with Powershell and use it?
Link to SDK: http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/

This is not a managed .NET dll. This is native c++ (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call C++ methods from PowerShell, although not directly. For this you need to use Platform Invoke (P/Invoke). Here are some articles you can start with:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/25/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzhw3s8.aspx

Also there are tools which generate C# code, which wraps C++ (like http://www.pinvoker.com/) that you can then use in your PowerShell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

On the theorical point of view, it can be loaded.

PowerShell can use .NET code and .NET can use PINVOKE to load natives DLLs.

But are you sure you need to create such an intricate system ?